# Suppress Error return in FOR /F loop

Tags: svn, batch-file

Here's what I'm doing right now

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a FINALSVN=0

cd %~dp0 ..\..\..
set SKETCHDIR=%CD%
for /D %%D IN (%SKETCHDIR%\*) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN ('@svn info %%D ^| FIND "Last Changed Rev: "') DO (SET STR=%%L)
    SET STR=!STR:Last Changed Rev: =!
    SET /a INT=!STR!
    if !INT! GTR !FINALSVN! SET FINALSVN=!INT!
)

echo !FINALSVN!

endlocal
exit /b
```

What I'm trying to do is get rid of the errors that svn info spits out at me.  I know that there are errors, and not all the directories will work.  That's the point, if it doesn't nothing happens.  I just want the errors to disappear.  I've tried placeing > NUL and ^>NUL in different places, and am finally at a loss.  Does anyone know of any solutions?

Comment: I believe the clue is in `errors`. `>NUL` suppresses messages to STDOUT. `2>NUL` should suppress messages to STDERR. (or `2^>NUL` as appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a FINALSVN=0

cd %~dp0 ..\..\..
set SKETCHDIR=%CD%
for /D %%D IN (%SKETCHDIR%\*) DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN ('@svn info %%D ^| FIND "Last Changed Rev: " ^>nul 2^>^&1') DO (SET STR=%%L)
   if "!STR!" NEQ "" (
    SET STR=!STR:Last Changed Rev: =!
    SET /a INT=!STR!
    if !INT! GTR !FINALSVN! SET FINALSVN=!INT!
   )
)

echo !FINALSVN!
```

endlocal
exit /b

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%L IN ('svn info %%D 2^>nul ^| FIND "Last Changed Rev: "') DO (SET STR=%%L)
```